# Does @row_number from MySQL 5 behave different in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql

Simple table `userpoints`:

```
userid | points
1      | 456
2      | 3
3      | 1778
...    | ...
```

I used this function for years in MySQL 5 to receive the userrank:

```
SELECT userid, userrank FROM 
    (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS userrank, userid 
    FROM `userpoints`, (SELECT @row_number := 0) r 
    ORDER BY points DESC) t 
    WHERE userid = 123
```

And it returned the userrank for userid `123`, e.g. `3456`.

With MySQL 8 I only get `1` as value for `userrank` with each userid I try.

What is the problem and how to fix this?

I tried the inner `SELECT` alone, and this gives me the list of all userids with the correct userranks.

Comment: looks like it is optimizing the t subquery to only look for userid=123.  have you tried an EXPLAIN?  you could do various things to try to defeat that, but unless you need your query to work on both 8 and 5.x, you should use the new row_number window function (or rank or dense_rank if you prefer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8, setting user variables as side-effects in expressions is deprecated. You should use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) instead.

```
SELECT t.userid, t.userrank 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS userrank, userid 
    FROM `userpoints` 
) t 
WHERE t.userid = 123;
```